# setInterval is blocking my script?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am doing slider library and i am confused about fact that i can use my Object ( i used module pattern ) just once. Let me show you:

```
let PapaSlide = (function(d) {
   'use strict';
    let _options = {}, _container, _items, _actIndex, _prevIndex;
    let _setOptions = function(opt) {
        return {
            container: opt.container || 'papa-container',
            items: opt.items || 'papa-item',
            transitionDuration: opt.transitionDuration || '300',
            transitionFunction: opt.transitionFunction || 'ease-in',
            timeInterval: opt.timeInterval || '3000',
            animationType: opt.animationType || 'fade',
            type: opt.type || 'auto',
            startAt: opt.startAt || 0
        }
    };
    let _setIndexes = function() {
        _options.startAt = _options.startAt > _items.length - 1 ? 0 : _options.startAt;
    _actIndex = _options.startAt;
    _prevIndex = ( _actIndex === 0 ) ? _items.length - 1 : _actIndex - 1; 
    };
    let _addTransitionStyle = function() {
        _items.forEach(item => {
            item.style.transitionDuration = `${_options.transitionDuration}ms`;
            item.style.transitionTimingFunction = _options.transitionFunction;
        });
    };
    let _sliderType = function() {
        _setIndexes();
        if(_options.animationType === 'fade' && _options.type === 'auto') {
            _autoFade();
        }
    };
    let _autoFade = function() {
        _items[_actIndex].style.opacity = 1;
        setInterval(() => { // is this blocking my other sliders?
            _prevIndex = _actIndex;
            _actIndex++;
            if(_actIndex > _items.length - 1) {
                _actIndex = 0;
            }
            _items[_prevIndex].style.opacity = 0;
            _items[_actIndex].style.opacity = 1;
        }, parseInt(_options.timeInterval));
    };
    let setPapaSlider = function(opt) {
        _options = _setOptions(opt);
        _container = d.getElementsByClassName(_options.container)[0];
        if(_container) {
            _items = Array.prototype.slice.call(_container.getElementsByClassName(_options.items));
            if(_items.length > 0) {
                _addTransitionStyle();
                _sliderType();
            }
            else {
               console.error('Items have been not found'); 
            }
        }
        else {
            console.error('Container has been not found');
        }
    };

    return {
        setPapaSlider: setPapaSlider
    }
})(document);
```

and my main.js

```
(function(PapaSlide) {
    "use strict";
    PapaSlide.setPapaSlider({container: 'fade-auto', timeInterval: '1200'});
    PapaSlide.setPapaSlider({container: 'fade-self', timeInterval: '2000'});
})(PapaSlide || {});
```

Actually, just container with 'fade-self' class is sliding, 'fade-auto' is stopped. Is this because javascript has one thread and setInterval is blocking another PapaSlide actions? I have consoled in console options and they have options which i type in arguments, so..? Should i use somewhere clearInterval? But these sliders are infinitive, so i think that i cannot.

EDIT

OK. I did something like this. I have deleted () from IFFE function. A just typed:

```
let fade1 = new PapaSlide();
fade1.setPapaSlide({container: 'fade-auto'});
let fade2 = new PapaSlide();
fade2.setPapaSlide({container: 'fade-self'});
```

Is this good solution?

Comment: I wrote in the answers why the original function you wrote down failed you. Your edit will definitely solve the problem. That being said, I'm assuming you're calling `PapaSlide()` with the global `document` variable?, and second, no need for the `new` operator (since PapaSlider is not a [constructor](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.constructors).

Comment: Is this written in es6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line, your second call to `PapaSlide.setPapaSlider` overrides your first call.

You call `setPapaSlider` twice, each time with different options. The first line in the function body is:

```
_options = _setOptions(opt)
```

so the first time you call it you save the options for `'fade-auto'` in the `_options` variable and the second time you call it, you've overridden it with the options for `'fade-self'`. Same goes for the rest of the variable scoped in the `PapaSlide` function.

Comment: Ok, get it. So my edit solve the problem and is it good practice? ( without new ).

Answer (score 0):

If you keep `PapaSlide` as a simple function like:

```
let PapaSlide = function(d) {
   'use strict';
    let _options = {}, _container, _items, _actIndex, _prevIndex;
    let _setOptions = function(opt) {
    };
    let _setIndexes = function() {
    };
    let _autoFade = function() {
    };
    let setPapaSlider = function(opt) {
    };

    return {
        setPapaSlider: setPapaSlider
    }
};
```

You can go ahead and do:

```
let fade1 = PapaSlide(document); //can get rid of document if you are not using it
fade1.setPapaSlide({container: 'fade-auto'});
let fade2 = PapaSlide(document);
fade2.setPapaSlide({container: 'fade-self'});
```

With this, each call to `PapaSlider` creates a scope of its own and returns an public interface having `setPapaSlider`.

Your code as opposed to this creates a public interface `{setPapaSlider: Function}` and applies `new` to it which doesn't look good to *me*

If you are using `es6` you could simplify this and make it more readable by using `class`.